# Is it possible to use 2 different retry beans for one service activator depending on an Exception thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I would like to do a serious retry for the service-activator only in case of a ConnectionException, for other exceptions I would like not to use a retry or a very light retry.  What configuration can I use?  The essence of my configuration is below:

```
<int:channel id="sDZCreationErrorChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="errorLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="sDZConnectionErrorChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="errorLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="sDZCreationErrorChannel" output-channel="outboundMailChannel">
    <int-mail:header-enricher>
        <int-mail:to value="${integration.sdz.email.to}"/>
        <int-mail:subject value="${integration.sdz.email.subject.creation}"/>
    </int-mail:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer ref="integrationEmailTransformer" method="transformToEmail"/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="sDZConnectionErrorChannel" output-channel="outboundMailChannel">
    <int-mail:header-enricher>
        <int-mail:to value="${integration.sdz.email.to}"/>
        <int-mail:subject value="${integration.sdz.email.subject.noconnection}"/>
    </int-mail:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer ref="integrationEmailTransformer" method="transformToEmail"/>
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="sDZCreationChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<!-- Processing Creation Chain -->
<int:chain input-channel="sDZCreationChannel" output-channel="debugLogger" 
    auto-startup="#{environment.getProperty('sd.zoo.enabled') == 'connect'}">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="500" />
    <int:filter ref="sDZIntegrationExistingRequestSentFilter" method="filter"/>
    <int:transformer ref="sDZCreationTransformer" method="transformOrder"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="sDZCreationServiceImpl" method="activateConfirmationCodes">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>

<int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel" default-output-channel="integrationDeadLetterErrorChannel">
    <int:mapping exception-type="com.smartdestinations.connect.integration.exception.sdz.SDZCreationResponseException" channel="sDZCreationErrorChannel"/>
    <int:mapping exception-type="com.smartdestinations.connect.integration.exception.sdz.SDZConnectionException" channel="sDZConnectionErrorChannel"/>
</int:exception-type-router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use one retry advice alongside with other. The `<request-handler-advice-chain>` strategy is to wrap one advice into another with the order how they are configured within the `<request-handler-advice-chain>`. So, if you declare one `retryAdvice` and then another, the first one won't be reached until the second will finish its work.

I don't see the whole picture yet how to easy achieve your requirements, but I really sure that you should deal with custom `RetryPolicy`, where you can reach a target exception via:

```
public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {
    Throwable t = context.getLastThrowable();
    ...
}
```

Pay attention to that useful `RetryContext` object.

There is also interested hook as a `RetryListener` abstraction with which you can set some additional attributes into that `RetryContext`. For example in the SI `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`:

```
public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
    context.setAttribute("message", messageHolder.get());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy?  If yes, do I need to overwrite it by my custom class or I can configure it in XML?

Comment: 1. You have to implement your own `RetryPolicy`. Yes `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` can be as sample for you. 2. You can to configure it in the XML afterward as regular `<bean>` and inject it into `RetryTemplate` bean.